# Regex check if word is in a sentence or outside

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex text replace that searches for `/\*\[(.*?)\]\*/ig` pattern and replaces it with `'<span style="font-size: 14px;">$1</span>'`. This works with a simple javascript **replace** function.

```
text = text.replace(/\*\[(.*?)\]\*/ig, '<span style="font-size: 14px;">$1</span>');
```

However, I want to know if the pattern is inside a sentence or not and set the font size accordingly.

Scenario sentence 1:

```
This is a text with the *[pattern]* inside the sentence.
```

Here the `*[pattern]*` should be replaced with `'<span style="font-size: 14px;">$1</span>'`. Notice the font size is 14px because the pattern is inside the sentence. Same goes for the following scenario:

```
*[pattern]* in the beginning.
```

or

```
End with a *[pattern]*
```

However in the following scenarios where the **patterns** aren't in sentences, I want the font size to be bigger, let's say 30px. This would apply to the following cases:

```
*[pattern]*
```

or

```
Text and then the pattern in the new line
*[pattern]*
```

or

```
 *[pattern]*
```

Here 3rd one represents with spaces but without other words.

Basically if the pattern is isolated from a sentence, I want it to have bigger font size. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lookahead like this:

```
/\*\[(.*?)\]\*(?=[^.\n]*\.)/g
```

for patterns "inside" sentences. Similarly,

```
/\*\[(.*?)\]\*(?=[^.\n]*(\n|$))/g
```

for "outside" ones.

http://jsfiddle.net/RCD83/

Comment: Looks great! I tried it out with many test cases. However this failed for one case: `End with a *[pattern]*`. Here the pattern is in a sentence but since the sentence doesn't end with a `.` the first expression fails. To solve this the first expression may be should look like this : `/\*\[(.*?)\]\*(?=[^.\n]*[\w\.])/g` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it with a single regex. We'll be using capture groups.

Don't let the length scare you: this is just the pattern, surrounded by two `(?:non-capturing groups)`

```
^(?:([ \t]*?)|([^\r\n]*?))\*\[[^\]]*\]\*(?:([ \t]*?)|([^\r\n]*?))$
```

1. Capture Group 1 is for then the part before `*[pattern]*` when it contains more than just spaces or tabs.
2. Capture Group 2 is for then the part after `*[pattern]*` when it contains more than just spaces or tabs.

In this [demo for the regex](http://regex101.com/r/xM7wA0), look at the capture groups in the bottom right pane.

**How to use it?**

In your replace lambda, just test for the length of Group 1 and Group 2. If it is more than zero, do one kind of replacement. Otherwise, do the other.

I won't write the code for you, but here's what a replace lambda looks like:

```
replaced = subject.replace(regex, function(m, group1, group2) {
    if ( group1 or group2 meet some magic code... ) return some span around m;
    else return some other span around m;;
});
```